# makefile to link each other

Tags: c++, makefile

I have multiple unit test files in a dir test, say "test_a.cc" "test_b.cc" "test_c.cc"(each one has its main function), and want to build every one into a executable file, then I will get "test_a", "test_b", "test_c", each one is a executable file.So how to write a general makefile to achieve my goal?

Currently, I am using a makefile like this, I want to discard the '.out' suffix:

```
SOURCES = $(shell find . -name '*.cc')
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cc=.o)
EXECUTABLE = $(SOURCES:.cc=.out)

all : $(EXECUTABLE)

%.out:%.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: You cannot link to `main()` multiple times. This isn't solvable with make alone.

Comment: I am surprised that people are still using make. SCONS/Gradle/....

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Each files has its own **main** functions.

Comment: @prepenguin Yeah I know, that's why you can't stitch them together.

Comment: @prepenguin Looks like you actually want to use a decent unit testing framework, like e.g. [google test](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Setting_up_a_New_Test_Project)

Comment: Do you have the source code ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do not want to link them into one executable file, each one will linking into a executable file.Is my describe misleading?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do not want to use gtest for small projects, please help me to improve the makefile.

Comment: @prepenguin You have to remove the `main()` functions from these source files then. Nothing you could _improve_ in the makefile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, I do not want to link them together.

Comment: @prepenguin - You need another technology than make.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My currently makefile is work, but i want to drop to '.out' suffix.

Comment: @EdHeal But I do not want to install other softwares, it's just a small project.

Comment: @prepenguin It's absolutely unclear now what you actually want to achieve. Three executables?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, just three executables, Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @prepenguin - The other systems can make multiple executables. Sort out dependencies. Have your own tasks etc.

Comment: @EdHeal Are you saying `make` can't? That's nonsense.

Comment: @EdHeal I know the GNU make can also meet the goal, but for my lacking knowledge of make, I do not know how to write the makefile.Thanks for your hint.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I have not said that. It can but there is better ways of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I want to discard the '.out' suffix"*

The simplest way to achieve this would be renaming the executable file after it was build:

```
%.out:%.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    mv $@ $(patsubst %.out,%,$@)
```

Another way would be to leave out the `.out`

```
SOURCES = $(shell find . -name '*.cc')
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cc=.o)
EXECUTABLE = $(SOURCES:.cc=)

all : $(EXECUTABLE)

% : %.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Any other elegant solutions? I think this solution is not so cool as i expected.

Comment: @prepenguin You may use explicit rules, not based on suffixes, or you provide a make template definition. Doing the latter one and provide it from an included `.mk` file would be the most _elegant_ IMHO, in terms of reusability. But that's not worth it for _small, simple projects_.

Comment: @prepenguin The even simplest solution is to drop the `.out` completely.